# How do I create a sublist from a list containing strings and numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list consisting of strings and integers:

```
{"abc", 3, 4, "def", 5, 6, 7, "xz", 8, 3}
```

and I would like to obtain:

```
{{"abc", 3, 4}, {"def", 5, 6, 7}, {"xz", 8, 3}}
```

The general problem is how to create sublists where the first element of each is a string, and the subsequent elements are numbers *until* the next element is a string, at which point the this string serves as the first element of the next sublist.

I would be grateful for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marked as a duplicate but let me leave this CW for clarity

```
list  = {"abc", 3, 4, "def", 5, 6, 7, "xz", 8, 3};

Split[list, ! StringQ[#2] &]
```

or (`V10.2+`)

```
SequenceCases[list, {_String, __?NumberQ}]
```